# Mahout Eigenvalue decomposition

Tags: hadoop, mahout, eigenvector

I am using Hadoop/Mahout to decompose what will become a very large sparse matrix. The problem is, I cannot even get it done with 200 nonzero-values and dimensions 56000 x 56000 which is solved in Python in under a second. I have a creeping suspicion that the computations become dense at some point!

I am using single node/core at this moment. Is this relevant? All operations are run from Java-files, not from the command line. The exception I get is and oldie but goodie:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.apache.mahout.math.DenseMatrix.<init>(DenseMatrix.java:50)
at org.apache.mahout.math.solver.EigenDecomposition.<init>(EigenDecomposition.java:70)
at myhadoop.MyHadoop.main(MyHadoop.java:84)
```

Java Result: 1

Naturally, since the Exceptions references DenseMatrix I get worried. If it is using an overridden method in some way, I could care less, but if actual zeros are being written it's not good. Also, my program runs very slowly.

The code:

```
SparseRowMatrix A = new SparseRowMatrix();    
// Matrix A is then created by adding elements one by one in a 
// somewhat ordered fashion.    
B SparseRowMatrix = A;    
B.transpose();    
A.plus(B);    
EigenDecomposition eigDec = new EigenDecomposition(A, true);    
myEig = eigDec.getRealEigenvalues();
```

Any ideas about how to make this truly sparse if it is in fact not?